# custom cursor in adobe edge

Tags: cursor, custom-attributes, adobe-edge

i am trying to make an custom cursor in adobe edge, without much sucess so i hope someone could help me.

these are the codes that i have tried;

```
var myCursor = new ball();// as linkage to be done in the library
Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEv­ent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);

function follow(evt:MouseEvent){ addChild(myCursor); 
myCursor.x = mouseX; 
myCursor.y = mouseY;
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.M­OUSE_LEAVE,vanish);
function vanish(event:Event){ removeChild(myCursor);
}
```

AND

```
.next:hover { cursor:url(img/right-pointer.png); }
```

AND

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, redrawCursor); 
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, hideCursor); 
Mouse.hide(); 

function redrawCursor (event:MouseEvent):void { 
sikte.visible = true; 
sikte.x = event.stageX; 
sikte.y = event.stageY; 
} 
function hideCursor (event:Event):void { sikte.visible = false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you completely new example:

1. Start a new Adobe Edge project.
2. Drag and drop on the stage image for cursor.
3. Name that image (div) e.g. "cursor".
4. Add event listener to your stage in order to get move events and set callback function. You can also make correction for position if your stage div is nested inside other div and/or it's position in window is not (0,0) - offset.

   ```
   document.getElementById('Stage').addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

   function mouseMove(e) {
       var offsetX = document.getElementById('Stage').offsetLeft;
       var offsetY = document.getElementById('Stage').offsetTop;

       var newX = e.pageX - offsetX;
       var newY = e.pageY - offsetY;
       sym.$("cursor").css({
           "left" : newX,
           "top" : newY
       });
   }
   ```
5. Set simple css for stage to make default cursor disappear. (cursor: none)

This is the minimum.